Как сделать цикл с помощью after в tkinter
Всем здравствуйте я решил сделать обычный рандомайзер в tkinter, и решил сделать что надпись
и кнопка мигали но не знаю как сделать. Помогите
import random
from tkinter import*
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Генератор случайных чисел")
def color_label_and_button()
    random_color_while = random.choice(["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "purple"])
    root.after(1,color_label_and_butto())
lab_to_enter_button = Label(root,text="Нажмите кнопку для генерации случайного числа \n"
                                      "         ᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯᐯ",bg=random_color_while)
lab_to_enter_button.pack()
root.mainloop()


root.after(1,color_label_and_butto()) - во-первых n потеряли в конце имени функции. Во-вторых, нужно передавать просто ссылку на функцию (имя функции) без скобок. Со скобками вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию, и результат ее передать в after, а нужно чтобы after сам ее внутри вызвал через указанное вермя.

Ну и полученное рандомное значение потом нужно выводить куда-то. У вас просто в холостую этот "цикл" будет крутиться без какого-то видимого результата.
